# SharePoint 2013 Custom List - Dataview with 2 columns grouping does not expand to show the items

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-server, grouping, dataview

I have a custom list view grouped by 2 columns (Requester Company & Month - Year). In my view, I can see the grouping without any issues with the total against each group.

When I expand the first group (Requester Company), I can see the results within the group. No problems there. However the issue is when I click the tiny arrow of the inner group (Month - Year column) it does not expand and show me the list items. **(Screen shot below)**

[image]

It's clearly visible that Dec - 1899 has 5 items, when I click for the first time, screen sort of shows something and then it disappears.

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause and the solution.

The cause was that the 2nd column (Month - Year) which is a calculated column, hence if there was no date in the source column, it shows 'Dec - 1899' as the calculated value. This was the culprit. I changed my formula to show 'No Date' if the source column is empty. and that fixed my expanding issue.

here's the updated formula:

```
=IF(Date="","No Date",TEXT(Date,"MMM")&" - "&YEAR(Date))
```